# dvc.api.read() raises an "UnicodeDecodeError"

Tags: python, encoding, dvc

I am trying to acess a DICOM file [image saved in the Digital Imaging and Communications in Medicine (DICOM) format]:

```
import dvc.api

path = 'dir/image.dcm'
remote = 'remote_name'
repo = 'git_repo'
mode = 'r'

data = dvc.api.read(path = path, remote = remote, repo = repo, mode = mode)
```

When I run the previous code, and after the "downloading progress bar" is complete, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "draft.py", line 7, in <module> mode ='r') File "C:\Users\lbrandao\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\dvc\api.py", line 91, in read return fd.read() File "C:\Users\lbrandao\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0] UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 764: character maps to <undefined>
```

I tried to overcome this issue by using the encoding argument:

```
data = dvc.api.read(path = path, remote = remote, repo = repo, mode = mode, encoding='ANSI')
```

Since, when I open a DICOM file using for example Notepad++, this is the encoding specified. However, it raises the error:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method Pool.__del__ of <dvc.fs.pool.Pool object at 0x0000021D1347A160>> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\lbrandao\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\dvc\fs\pool.py", line 42, in __del__ File "C:\Users\lbrandao\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\dvc\fs\pool.py", line 46, in close File "C:\Users\lbrandao\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\dvc\fs\ssh\connection.py", line 71, in close File "C:\Users\lbrandao\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 194, in close File "C:\Users\lbrandao\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 185, in _log File "C:\Users\lbrandao\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp.py", line 158, in _log File "C:\Users\lbrandao\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1372, in log File "C:\Users\lbrandao\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1441, in _log File "C:\Users\lbrandao\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1411, in makeRecord TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I also tried `encoding = 'utf-8'`, but the "UnicodeDecodeError" continues to appear:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "draft.py", line 7, in <module> mode ='r', encoding='utf-8') File "C:\Users\lbrandao\anaconda3\envs\ccab_env_dev\lib\site-packages\dvc\api.py", line 91, in read return fd.read() File "C:\Users\lbrandao\anaconda3\envs\ccab_env_dev\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 140: invalid continuation byte
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks.

Comment: @Ibrando how do you process it later? Shouldn't you use `rb` mode?

Comment: @don_pablito I ran again the code, this time with mode='rb', but I got the error TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable ...

Comment: That sounds like a bug, could you create issue on github? https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues

Comment: Done: https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/6414

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with dvc.api, but a lot of people who deal with DICOMs use either pydicom or simpleITK. I wrote a library which can get most of the the data using either ([cleanX](https://github.com/drcandacemakedamoore/cleanX/)) and you can look at [an example notebook here](https://github.com/drcandacemakedamoore/cleanX/blob/main/workflow_demo/classes_workflow.ipynb).

Comment: The scope of using dvc.api.read() is only to retrieve/stream the data files from DVC remote to a Python script. Only afterwards can Pydicom, etc be used for further manipulation.